# Objective-C NSPopover statusItem not opening

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsstatusitem, nspopover

I'm having difficulty getting my NSPopover to function properly. The statusItem pops up in the status bar, and highlights on click, but the popover isn't displaying.

Here's the structure of my code.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSStatusItem *statusItem;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSEvent *popoverTransiencyMonitor;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSPopover *popover;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSView *popoverView;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    self.statusItem.highlightMode = YES;
    [self.statusItem.image setTemplate:YES];
    self.statusItem.action = @selector(itemClicked:);
}

-(void)itemClicked:(id)sender {
    [[self popover] showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];

    if (self.popoverTransiencyMonitor == nil) {
        self.popoverTransiencyMonitor = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSLeftMouseDownMask | NSRightMouseDownMask | NSKeyUpMask) handler:^(NSEvent* event) {
            [NSEvent removeMonitor:self.popoverTransiencyMonitor];
            self.popoverTransiencyMonitor = nil;
            [self.popover close];
        }];
    }
}
```

I got help from another person on StackOverflow, Gavin, and that help is located here. [NSPopover transiency when popover is in status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054244/nspopover-transiency-when-popover-is-in-status-bar)

I reached out to Gavin, and he managed to help me out by sending me his xCode project and it gave me some insight. But our code matches, mine doesn't work, and his does.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you describe what's wrong with your code in details?

Comment: As far as I can tell, nothing is wrong with the code. It's just not popping up when the statusItem is clicked for some reason. When it's clicked it should send the notification and call the itemClicked class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit embarrassing, but it seems that the issue was that I created a project which uses Storyboards, and NSPopover wouldn't work with that for some reason.

Sorry for the clutter.